# Get File path not apache tomcat path

Tags: java, apache, file, tomcat, jasper-reports

I'm trying to load a jasper report from my project's directory, but when I start the application, it gives me an error about file location, it says:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin\report.jasper
```

To get the file path, I use this:

```
new File("report.jasper").getAbsolutePath()
```

If I run that in a simple class, it gives me the right path, but when I run the application it gives me the tomcat's path, I tried some other functions like `getCanonicalPath`, `getCanonicalFile` and `getAbsoluteFile`; but it's always the same result.

Is there a solution respect this? My application will run on both platforms: Windows and Linux, it will be annoying place the report's file in the each respective tomcat's path everytime I update the application, I'm trying not to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is located inside the web app root you should use servlet context to ask it the realpath
[as javadoc explains](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Another way is to user getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() , but you can use it only if you don't have the need of knowing the filepath.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Class#getResource(String name) or ClassLoader#getResource(String name) method both returns URL object and than you can use Url#getPath() to get the path.